# Open XLSX file that protected by a password with PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I'm trying to open an Excel file (.xlsx) that is protected by a password with [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) ([documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#reading-a-spreadsheet)). I know the password but I don't find a way to open it.

The `load()`method of `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx` doesn't give the possibility to insert a password and when I try to load the file it returns an error (of course).

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('hello world.xlsx');
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
echo $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue() . "\n";
```

And here is the error

> Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 311
>       Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 313
>       Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 350
>       Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 311
>       Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 313
>       Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 397
>       Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 311
>       Warning: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 313
>       Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 1855
>       Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /PHPOffice/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 1883

How can this code deal with passwords?

Comment: Looking for the same info, and I am starting to think it isn't possible, or it is the best kept secret in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I welcome you to check out my [PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword](https://github.com/jaydadhania08/PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword) repo.

It also works for DOCX/PPTX files, but this answer is specific to your question: first *decrypt* the file with password, and then use the decrypted file with PHPSpreadsheet.

Here is an example:

```
require_once('PHPDecryptXLSXWithPassword.php');

$encryptedFilePath = 'hello world.xlsx';
$password = 'mypassword'; // password to "open" the file
$decryptedFilePath = 'temp_path_to_decrypted_file.xlsx';

decrypt($encryptedFilePath, $password, $decryptedFilePath);

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($decryptedFilePath);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
echo $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue() . "\n";
```

**Note:** This is an experimental code, so use with caution. DO NOT use in production!

Answer (score 0):

At this moment i can't try but, I suppose that you have to do something like this:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('hello world.xlsx');
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('THEPASSWORD');
echo $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue() . "\n";
```

I'm not sure, tomorrow I will be to the office and can try.

Comment: It crashes when using `$reader->load()` because the password protects the document (not only workbook)

Comment: You are right! I was reading the implementation and also the Xls reader in the "password managment" zone seems like a joke.