# PhpSpreadsheet how to read xlsx Workbook password protected file

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I use *PhpSpreadsheet* for read `xlsx` file. How to open `xlsx` passowrd protected file?

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('file.xlsx');  
$spreadsheet->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword('111111');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941725/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open XLSX file that protected by a password with PHPSpreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941725/open-xlsx-file-that-protected-by-a-password-with-phpspreadsheet)